# How to parse string to Time & rangeto Date by ORM

Tags: go, time, controller, beego

Problem is i cant filter by date range to date. It gives me zero data. But i have many data at 2019/5/7

```
timeT := "2019-5-8"
startT, err := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, timeT)

xxx := now.New(startT).BeginningOfMonth()
yyy := now.New(startT).EndOfMonth()

_, err = o.QueryTable("BillDetail").Filter("OriginalID", id).Filter("Date", xxx).Filter("Date", yyy).All(&bills)

    if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}

return bills, err
```

I used

> "time"
>
> "github.com/jinzhu/now"
>
> "github.com/astaxie/beego/orm"

I used debug and i found this output on console

```
[ORM]2019/05/08 15:12:22  -[Queries/default] - [  OK /    db.Query /    16.9ms] - [SELECT T0.`i_d`, T0.`date`, T0.`name`, T0.`original_i_d`, T0.`value` FROM `bill_detail` T0 WHERE T0.`original_i_d` = ? AND T0.`date` = ? AND T0.`date` = ? ] - `6`, `0001-01-01 08:00:00`, `0001-01-01 08:00:00`
```

Pay your attention here

```
`0001-01-01 08:00:00`, `0001-01-01 08:00:00`
```

Comment: Never ignore errors. Your input time (`2019-5-8`) is invalid, but you don't notice, because you're ignoring the error.

Comment: @Flimzy I just don't get it. There is no error I guess. `"yearMonth":"2019/5/8"` used this one. Can you explain more?

Comment: `startT, err := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, timeT)` returns an error, which you ignore. Don't ignore it. See [here](https://play.golang.org/p/QkGqYncZfQF).

Comment: Read the error, and you will know what you did wrong. You're trying to parse an invalid date. So it returns the zero value for the date, and an error. Don't ignore that error. Ignoring the error is what you're doing wrong.

Comment: There is no error, if there is any error it would show me. But invalid date ? I used the `https://yourbasic.org/golang/format-parse-string-time-date-example/` this one.

Comment: There absolutely is an error. See [here](https://play.golang.org/p/QkGqYncZfQF) for proof. The problem is that you're ignoring the error. That's why it doesn't show you.

Comment: @Flimzy `err =  parsing time "2019-05-08 08:00:00" as "2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00": cannot parse " 08:00:00" as "T"` my bad sorry.

Comment: That doesn't even match the code in your question. _Always paste exact code_ if you want meaningful help.

Comment: But I'm glad you found the problem. Good luck with the rest.